# Changing lighting & color_type for OpenGL Render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, opengl

When I render with [bpy.ops.render.opengl](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.render.html?highlight=bpy%20ops%20render%20opengl#bpy.ops.render.opengl), the shading appears to always be `SOLID` shading. If this is the case, how do I change the solid render's `light` & `color_type`? When the `view_context` argument is set to `True,` the shading will match the active Viewport, however when it is `False`, the shading is always "MATERIAL" and the light is "STUDIO."

```py
import bpy

my_areas = bpy.context.workspace.screens[0].areas
for area in my_areas:
    for space in area.spaces:
        if space.type == "VIEW_3D":
            space.shading.light = "FLAT"
            space.shading.color_type = "TEXTURE"

bpy.types.View3DShading.light = "FLAT"
bpy.ops.render.opengl( animation = True, view_context = False )
bpy.ops.render.play_rendered_anim()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the shading type for OpenGL can only be `SOLID`, but the `light` and `color_type` can be set as such (thank you to Jacob Merrill @BluePrintRandom):

```py
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].display.shading.light= "FLAT"
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].display.shading.color_type = "TEXTURE"
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3D Viewport uses the [Workbench](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/workbench/index.html) render engine, for SOLID mode and the opengl snapshot code simply copies the scene using that engine. You can change any of the [SceneDisplay](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SceneDisplay.html) properties to render.  You can also change any of the [View3DShading](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.View3DShading.html) properties so that you can, for instance, use a Matcap material.

Here's an example of setting various properties and then rendering with opengl:

```py
win = bpy.context.window
scr = win.screen
areas3d  = [area for area in scr.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D']
area = areas3d[0]
space = area.spaces[0]
regions   = [region for region in areas3d[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW']

shading = space.shading
shading.type='SOLID' # 'WIREFRAME' 'SOLID', 'MATERIAL', 'RENDERED'
shading.light='MATCAP' # 'MATCAP' 'STUDIO' 'FLAT'
shading.color_type='MATERIAL' # 'MATERIAL', 'SINGLE', 'OBJECT', 'RANDOM', 'VERTEX', 'TEXTURE'
shading.studio_light='metal_carpaint.exr'
bpy.ops.render.opengl()
```

Note that to set the properties we using the space_data for the View3D area.